# Finding simple functions to bound $\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to show that

$$
\int\limits_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,d(\mu\times\mu).
$$ equals $\infty$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. I've tried to find simple functions that give lower bounds to $\dfrac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ in the area close to $(0,0)$. I want to split up $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ into $R_1,R_2,\ldots$, where $R_i$ is the region such that $\dfrac{1}{i+1}\leq \max(x,y)\leq \dfrac{1}{i}$. The area of the region $R_i$ is $\dfrac{2i+1}{i^2(i+1)^2}$.

I want to find an lower bound for $\dfrac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ in the region $R_i$, so that the eventual sum of the simple function diverges. But I can't seem to find a bound that works.

Comment: Why not replace $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the quarter circle contained in it and centered at the origin, and use polar coordinates?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Then we will be left with $\int\frac{\sin 2\theta}{R^2}$. I'm not quite sure how that helps find a lower bound... ($\sin<1$, but that's an upper bound.)

Comment: What you are left with is more elaborate than that. And it easily gives lower bounds that give the result you want.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Do you mean I made a calculation mistake? Using $x=R\cos\theta,y=R\sin\theta$ we have $\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{R^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{R^4} = \frac{(1/2)\sin(2\theta)}{R^2}$, where the integral is over $R\in[0,1],\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Yes, so far so good. This is not all you need to do to change variables.

Comment: Anyway, once you have the right expression, note that except for two wedges, one at the $x$-axis, and the other at the $y$-axis, you may assume that $\sin(2\theta)\ge1/2$. And it also helps to know that $\int_0^1\frac1x\,dx$ diverges.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Oh, I need the $2\times 2$ matrix for change of variables. I believe it has entries $\cos\theta,\sin\theta,-R\sin\theta,R\cos\theta$ in this order, so its determinant is $R$. Multiply that to get $\frac{(1/2)\sin(2\theta)}{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the subset where $\frac12<\frac{y}{x}<2$.  On this set, $4xy>x^2+y^2$. So your integrand is bounded below on this set by $\dfrac{1/4}{x^2+y^2}$.  For simplicity, we can also consider just the part where $x\leq \frac12$ to get

$$
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,d(\mu\times\mu)
&\geq\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}x}^{2x}\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}\int_0^{\frac12}\left(\dfrac{\arctan(2)}{x}-\dfrac{\arctan(\frac12)}{x}\right)\,dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\arctan(2)-\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)\int_0^{\frac12}\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx.
\end{align*}$$